# error installing scikit learn on mac

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I get the following error while trying to install scikit learn on mac. I do not seem to find any solution to this problem. Can somebody help?

```
xxxx-MacBook-Pro:site-packages xxxx$ sudo pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-     learn
Downloading/unpacking numpy from    https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy- 1.9.1.tar.gz#md5=78842b73560ec378142665e712ae4ad9
  Downloading numpy-1.9.1.tar.gz (4.0Mb): 4.0Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/build/numpy/setup.py:160: Warning:      'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/build/numpy/setup.py", line 160
    with open('.gitmodules') as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/build/numpy/setup.py:160: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/build/numpy/setup.py", line 160

with open('.gitmodules') as f:

        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Output of which pip:

```
//anaconda/bin/pip
```

Comment: While this may not work for you, I've noticed that I can get issues where numpy/pandas/scikit-learn even with pip don't build right on a machine, then I go ahead and use a package manager like canopy and viola they just work.  It there any possibility you might switch to Canopy isntead of system python?

Comment: can you please add the output of `which pip` to your question?

Comment: output of which pip has been added.

Comment: okay, there is something going on here. Can you also add `sudo which pip`?